# Wicket RestartResponseException with session

Tags: java, session, wicket

We have two URL-mounted pages (running Wicket 6.11). When the browser (tried with Chromium) opens the URL for page 1 with a certain parameter, the constructor saves an information in the session and redirects to page 2 (pseudo-code):

```
public Page1(Pageparameters parameters) {
    super(parameters);

    String value = parameters.get("magicProperty").toString();
    if (value != null && isValid(value)) {
       Serializable key = createKey(value);
       getSession().setAttribute("key", key);
       throw new RestartResponseException(Page2.class);
    }
}
```

In the page 2 constructure we want to get the key from the session again:

```
public Page2(PageParameters parameters) {
    super(parameters);

    Serializable key = getSession().getAttribute("key");
    ...
}
```

The problem is, that when the browser is freshly opened, the `key` in page 2 is `null` - it looks like the session object is freshly created for page 2. How can I resolve/work around this problem?

Comment: RestartResponseException to Page2 will call the "Page2()" constructor (without PageParameters).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know why but before throwing the `RestartResponseException` it looks like I need to invoke `session.bind()`:

```
public Page1(Pageparameters parameters) {
    super(parameters);

    String value = parameters.get("magicProperty").toString();
    if (value != null && isValid(value)) {
       Serializable key = createKey(value);
       Session session = getSession();
       session.setAttribute("key", key);
       session.bind();
       throw new RestartResponseException(Page2.class);
    }
}
```